# SQL Query works in workbench but gives syntax error in java

Tags: java, mysql, syntax, mysql-workbench

I ran the query in both sql Workbench and in the executeUpdate() method in java:

in Workbench:

```
INSERT INTO recentsearches (name) VALUES ("blah");
```

in java:

```
statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO recentsearches (name) VALUES (\""+name+"\""));
```

Assuming name = "blah". But I get a syntax error from running the query in java, I've already checked the string value for name. It definitely comes up as "blah", and I didn't forget the speech marks around string values, yet I still get a syntax error.

The error I get in my console is:

> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: Perhaps `"INSERT INTO recentsearches (name) VALUES ('"+name+"')"`

Comment: I tried that, it comes up with the same error:

Comment: check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: "INSERT INTO recentsearches (name) VALUES("+name+")";
My advice, use PreparedStatement.

Comment: can I just why it worked, when "INSERT INTO recentsearches (name) VALUES('"+name+"')" didn't.

Comment: the two statements are clearly the same, why would one work but not the otehr

Comment: By me it's not the same, the String representation of your statement will looks as follows:
INSERT INTO recentsearches (name) VALUES('somename');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
"INSERT INTO recentsearches (name) VALUES("+name+")";
```

My advice, use PreparedStatement because it has:

-Precompilation and DB-side caching of the SQL statement leads to overall faster execution and the ability to reuse the same SQL statement in batches.

-Automatic prevention of SQL injection attacks by builtin escaping of quotes and other special characters. Note that this requires that you use any of the PreparedStatement setXxx() methods to set the values